# Read the Windows Registry from Chrome Extension

Tags: c++, google-chrome, npapi, ppapi

I built a browser extension with Firebreath a couple of years ago, but now I realized that it isn't working anymore on Chrome because it doesn't support NPAPI anymore.

The extension reads the Windows Registry and returns a value.

Does anyone know what can I use to do the same in Chrome these days?

EDIT:
After hours of work, I'm able to run the extension and the host app, but everytime I try to receive data, I get undefined.

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char message[] = "{\"t\": \"t\"}";

    unsigned int len = strlen(message);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin),  _O_BINARY);

    printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, (char) 0);

    printf("%s", message);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: +1 because this seems like an interesting question others might have.  I'm a little surprised you got a down-vote without some explanation.  My guess is perhaps someone felt like you hadn't done any research.

Answer (score 4):

[Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is the only thing that would be able to do what you want.

Comment: As of Jan 15 2020, Chrome apps are being discontinued: https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/moving-forward-from-chrome-apps.html . Does anyone know of a way to do native messaging in chrome extensions?

Comment: Chrome extensions support native messaging extensions